# blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery Extension Error: this.container.children is not a function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gallery, blueimp

I need your help.

I have a WORKING blueimp gallery using lightbox. I wanted to add the extension shown here: 
https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

The idea was to achieve the extra design when clicking on a thumbnail (the white modal surround the image).

Since the blueimp gallery is already working, it should be a simple change for me however I'm getting an error. This appears on firebug:

```js
TypeError: this.container.children is not a function
http://www.smile-fnd/js/blueimp-gallery/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js
Line 1

...)return d.call(this,a,b,c);var e=this,f=this.container.children(".modal"),g=f.cl...
```

Specifically the error is on `f=this.container....`

I believe I have followed the documentation, so I don't understand why it is failing.
Note again that the blueimp gallery is working fine without the extension. If I comment out the inclusion of `bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js` everything is fine, but of course without the design I wanted.

Here is part of my code:

```html
<!-- Include the Gallery stylesheet in the head section of your webpage -->
<?php 
    //CAKEPHP - The links are fine
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap/bootstrap.min');
 echo $this->Html->css('blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min');
 echo $this->Html->css('blueimp-gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min');

    echo $this->Html->script('jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js');
 echo $this->Html->script('jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js');
 //Bootstrap
 echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap/bootstrap.min');
?>

<!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Collapsible Panel for the Images -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="margin: 50px 0px 20px 0px;">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading arrowIcon">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="form-step"> <!-- collapsed -->
      Photos 
      <?php if($count >= GLOBAL_MAX_IMAGES) { ?>
      <small class="text-danger"> - Maximum number of uploaded images reached!</small>
      <?php } ?>
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"> <!-- remove "in" to collapse -->
   <div class="panel-body">
    
    <!-- Create a list of links to image files, optionally with enclosed thumbnails and add them to the body of your webpage, before including the Gallery script: -->
    <div id="galleryLinks">
    <?php
     if (file_exists(WWW_ROOT.$path)) {
      //Scan Given Directory for Images
      $first_exam_dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.$path);
      $images = $first_exam_dir->find('.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)');
   
      if(!empty($images)) {
       foreach($images as $file) {
        //Exclude Thumbnails
        if( preg_match('#^(?!'.GLOBAL_THUMB_SUFFIX.').#', $file) ) {
         //Generate Gallery Links
         echo '<a href="'.$this->webroot.$path.$file.'" title="'.$file.'" data-gallery>';
         //If Thumbnail exists
         if( file_exists($path.GLOBAL_THUMB_SUFFIX.$file) ) { 
          echo '<img style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right:5px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="'.$this->webroot.$path.GLOBAL_THUMB_SUFFIX.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'">';
         }
         else {
          echo $file;
         }
         echo '</a>';
        }
       }
      }
     }
     else {
      echo '<span class="text-danger">WARNING! The directory for images does not exist!'
      .'<br />Please edit this record once before you upload any images (Just click Edit -> Save). By doing so the directory will be created automatically.</span>';
     }
    ?>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Include the Gallery script at the bottom of the body of your webpage: -->
<?php 
    //CAKEPHP - the links are fine
 echo $this->Html->script('blueimp-gallery/blueimp-gallery.min');
 echo $this->Html->script('blueimp-gallery/bootstrap-image-gallery.min');
?>

<!-- Add the following JavaScript code after including the Gallery script, to display the images in the Gallery lightbox on click of the links: -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 document.getElementById('galleryLinks').onclick = function (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  target = event.target || event.srcElement,
  link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
  options = {index: link, event: event},
  links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
 };
  });
```

Here's a screenshot as well!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the JS file and try the next change:

`this.container`

by

`$(this.container)`

or

`jQuery(this.container)`

Comment: Could you explain _why_ this fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue. The fix was easy just use:

```
blueimp-gallery/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js
```

instead of:

```
blueimp-gallery/blueimp-gallery.min.js
```

**Possible cause:** If you are using jQuery in the project you should also be using jQuery version of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue.
You can resolve by changing

```
this.container.children
```

by

```
this.container.find
```

then you will see a new error on

```
f.clone
```

so change it by

```
$(f).clone
```

It worked for me!